# PasteSpecial and xlPasteValues

Tags: excel, vba

I can't really find out how to set the paste mode to xlPasteValues where do I attach this?

```
Set ActiveListWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
ActiveListWB.Sheets("Resources").Range("D2:CI206").Copy WSNew1.Range("D2") _

WSNew1.Name = Split(ActiveListWB.Name, "_")(0) & " - Resources"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in one line if you want to specify the paste method:

```
ActiveListWB.Sheets("Resources").Range("D2:CI206").Copy WSNew1.Range("D2")
```

should be:

```
ActiveListWB.Sheets("Resources").Range("D2:CI206").Copy
WSNew1.Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Not sure why you have an underscore at the end though, that would make the code expect a continuation of that line on the next line.